# Why gem doesn't appear in local gems after bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

I'm using `Docker` and `rbenv`.

I want to **install the gem** `httparty` so I ran : `docker-compose run web bundle install`

In the logs bundle I can see that the gem has been **succesfully installed** :

```
...
Using httparty 0.16.2 from https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty.git (at master@da1b1ad)
...
```

Then when I try to launch server with `docker-compose up` I get this **error in logs** :

> > web_1         | https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty.git (at master@da1b1ad) is not yet
> >     web_1         | checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
> >     web_1         | Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.6) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.0). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

`bundler` is already installed.
I ran : `docker-compose run web  gem list`, **the gem doesn't appear on the list** but it appears if I run : `docker-compose run web bundle env` :

```
...
DEPENDENCIES
   httparty!
...
```

**So why the gem doesn't seem to be really installed while bundle say that it is ?**

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker-compose build` solved the issue.

Comment: A better approach I would strongly recommend is to **mount a volume from another container** for the gems. This prevents needing to re-build the entire container every time the gems change. There are many posts about this on the internet, such as: https://medium.com/magnetis-backstage/how-to-cache-bundle-install-with-docker-7bed453a5800